# Duplicate entry error in customize signup form in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-authentication, django-allauth

We have a django project app name "blog". We have built customized signup for same having  fields like : Name ,mobile,email and password. 
In MYSQL DB , it is giving "Duplicate Entry Error " for table blog_Customuser and entry is made into table for email,password ,but no entry made for mobile column. Also no entries made to account_emailaddress table.

Also while debugging the code ,doesn't stop at any below lines code marked for debug.

Entry into Settings.py -

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'blog.forms.AllauthUserRegisterForm'
```

Form.py entry looks like this:

```
class AllauthUserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Name'}))
mobile = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Mobile'}))
#password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput)
class Meta:
    model = CustomUser
    fields = ['email', 'mobile']
```

Models.py entry looks like this:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
name = models.CharField(default='', max_length=200, blank=True)
mobile = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
# to enforce that you require email field to be associated with
# every user at registration
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["mobile"]
def __str__(self):
    return self.email

Table blog_customuser column details 
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `password` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
 `last_login` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
 `is_superuser` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `username` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 `first_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `last_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `is_staff` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `date_joined` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
 `mobile` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
 `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: In `CustomUser`, `mobile` is `PositiveIntegerField` and this translates in `ModelForm` to `IntegerField`, but in `AllauthUserRegisterForm` you created another field (duplicate) `mobile` as a `CharField`

Comment: Also  when i debug code with breakpoints on Allauthuser & Customuser , process doesn't stop over there .

Comment: No, it's gonna stop/crash while saving to DB

Comment: removed the mobile entry from forms.py ,still getting this error "(1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key 'username'")" . Data submitted to table customuser is NULL entries which is causing the duplicate error . Any idea what i m missing here.@yusef BH

Comment: Thanks @YusefBH for help.